# Labelling a plotmap of self organizing map in Matlab(edited)

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, som

I want to label the plothitmap `plotsomhits(net,inputs)` of the iris dataset found in the neural network toolbox. How would I do that. I want the class labels to be superimposed on the plothitmap. Any ideas?It would look something like this:

[image]

Is it possible?Thanks.

Comment: it would be nice if we can actually reproduce this plot (or at least some minimal code). How does it originally look like? How do you know where to put which label? etc

Comment: Don't ask individual users of this site to help you. If you just post the question properly it is likely to get the attention it deserves, and otherwise it will surely stand out with the bounty you gave it.

Answer (score 3):

If the built-in function to display the label not available for *plotsom...* function, you may want to consider using manual annotation on each cell using *annotationtextbox* function as described in this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextboxproperties.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the coordinates that each class label corresponds to you can just do:

```
plotsomhits(net,inputs);
text(x1,y1,label1); //this will put a text label superimposed on the current plot
```

Of course if you have lots of lablels, then you can iterate over a for loop to add the labels.

Here is a link to documentation on how to use `text` [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)